# What is the package route between Subscriber and Publisher in a multi-machine ROS network?

Tags: ros, publisher, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Assuming to have a multi-machine ROS network where there is a Master running on a remote server, and both the Subscriber and the Publisher in a local network; does the packets exchanged between the Subscriber and the Publisher need to reach the remote server?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276636/what-is-the-package-route-between-subscriber-and-publisher-in-a-multi-machine-ros-network?/) by [piti_wity](https://answers.ros.org/users/31842/piti_wity/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-11-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Assuming [..] there is a Master running on a remote server, and [..] Subscriber and the Publisher in a local network; does the packets exchanged between the Subscriber and the Publisher need to reach the remote server?

No.

See [wiki/ROS/Concepts](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Concepts) (*ROS Computation Graph Level* section), and [wiki/Master](http://wiki.ros.org/Master).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0